# Regex to match string literal enclosed in quotes without matching others

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

So I am writing a simple lexer for a subset of the C language in python. I am using re to match and find all my tokens but am having issues with my string literal token matching. To match my string literal I am using: `r'(?<=").*(?=")`
I am doing this non-inclusive because I am wanting to match my double quotes as quote tokens and the content inbetween them as a string literal token. It works fine if a string literal is used only once in a line but if I do `"hello"  int i "what is up"` I end up matching `hello` correctly but then matching `int i` because it is inbetween double quotes also. How can I prevent this. Right now all of my input is read in at once into one line.

EDIT:
I found out my possible issue. I was using a greedy expression with `.*` I switched it to `.*?` and it is matching correctly. It started matching as `hello"  int i "what is up` and that is where discovered it was being greedy. My new regex is : `r'(?<=").*?(?=")` Does anyone see any possible conflicts now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a lookahead, you could try this (which will consume the last `"` so that it does not start a new capture):

```
import re
text = '"hello"  int i "what is up"'
print(re.findall(r'"(.*?)"', text))
# ['hello', 'what is up']
```

Comment: I found this out too but I am wanting to not consume. I think I have come up with the solution. I will edit.